# how to compare two inner array of object from javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of an object X and y, form `x` `value` array `["N","Y"]`, I need to filter the `y` array options value, based on that I need to return the `y` array, I had tried with this:

```js
const x = [{"application":"Collect","attr":[{"name":"document","value":["N","Y"],"disabled":true}, {"name":"video","value":["Y"],"disabled":false}]}]
const y = [{"name":"document","options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"},{"name":"view", value:"view"}]}]

const iArr = x[0].attr.map(m => {
  m.value.map(o => {
    y.map(yl => {
      yl.options.filter(s => {
        if (o === s.value) {
          console.log(s)
        }
      })
    })
  })
})

console.log(iArr)
```

my output should be

```
const result = [{"name":"document","options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"}]}]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide details how you would like to determine the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here to alter the value of each element in y according to the attr details in x.

We [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) each element.options in y by the corresponding attr value in x.

In this example, I'm presuming that the rules that apply to each element in y reside in the same attribute index , e.g. x[0].attr[index].

```js
const x = [{"application":"Collect","attr":[{"name":"document","value":["N","Y"],"disabled":true}, {"name":"video","value":["Y"],"disabled":false}]}]
const y = [{"name":"document 1","options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"},{"name":"view", value:"view"}]},
  {"name":"document 2","options":[{"name":"Yes","value":"Y"},{"name":"No","value":"N"},{"name":"view", value:"view"}]}]

const result = y.map((element, index) => {
    let res = { ... element };
    res.options = element.options.filter(option => x[0].attr[index].value.includes(option.value));
    return res;
}); 

console.log("Result:",result);
```

Comment: i am getting error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Oh dear, apologies for that! Perhaps I'm using slightly different input data?

Comment: yes if i use `attr` has multple object that time is not working

Comment: i had updated the question can u check that. `attr[0]` we sholud not keep static it can be dynamic

Comment: Ah yes, I see! So we should replace attr[0] with attr[index]? That is, each element of attr applies to the same element in y?

Comment: if its `attr` has multiple objects i am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined`

Comment: I've updated the answer, I hope it's nearer to the desired behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one element in the x array then you could to this

```js
const x = [{
  "application": "Collect",
  "attr": [{
    "name": "document",
    "value": ["N", "Y"],
    "disabled": true
  }]
}]

const y = [{
  "name": "document",
  "options": [{
    "name": "Yes",
    "value": "Y"
  }, {
    "name": "No",
    "value": "N"
  }, {
    "name": "view",
    "value": "view"
  }]
}]



const result = y.map(z => ({
  ...z,
  options: z.options.filter(k => x[0].attr[0].value.includes(k.value))
}));
console.log(result)
```